# Find out how unlikely Y is than X -- when X is 50% more likely to cure cancer than Y

Tags: statistical-significance

So 50% likely to me sounds like 150% percent that X will cure cancer, and 100% that Y will cure cancer. Other than this, I have NO IDEA without googling how to figure this out. Detailed explanation is good.

**edit: 66% unlikely (or likely???) that Y will cure cancer when compared to X --**

**now What are the basic rules that is needed to figure this out, along with other similar problems?**

Comment: I don't understand this! If Y will cure cancer for 2% of patients (in some relevant group), then with your assumptions X will cure 3% oy your patients. I have no idea where younget those 150% from, and neither what it could mean. You should try to reformulate!

Comment: 2/3 = 66% | 100/150 = 66% | y/x=ANSWER || was that too hard to answer?

Comment: About your request to migrate to math.se, Math moderators and I agree that this question can stay on Cross Validated. However, I would like to remind you that *respectful and constructive comments* are more likely to attract good answers and generate fruitful exchanges on SE sites.

Comment: It is hard to make sense of the (ungrammatical) phrase "find out how unlikely Y is than X," which leaves many readers guessing what this question might mean. Could you please clarify it?

Comment: @kittensatplay, after reviewing several of your contributions to the site, I think you may benefit from reading the first few sections of the [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq), which address accepted practices on how to ask questions. You may also want to look at section on [etiquette](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette).

Answer (score 2):

Call the probability that Y cures cancer $a$. Since X is 50% more likely to cure cancer, its probability of curing cancer is $b = 1.5 \times a$.

If you do not know the probability that X cures cancer you are stuck. If you know that it is 0.15 (say) then $a$ is 0.10.

Comment: so ur saying there isnt an inverse to finding out "how unlikely Y is than X" given "X is 50% more likely" ....so ur telling me that when these garbage sites tell me that "X is P% more likely to Z than Y" -- it is completely useless and meaningless because the whole of these people dont know any math... because few teachers can teach us math properly. ok

Comment: If $a=80$%, say, do you want the reader to conclude that $1.5\times 80$% = $120$% is a *probability*? Really?